# Can't load external JSON in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm having a problem loading JSON from a URL. Here's what I have:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: 'application' });

App.OrdersListController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.OrdersListView = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: 'orders' });

App.Order = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Order.reopenClass({
  find: function(){
     //not implemented yet 
  },
  findAll: function(){
      var content = [];
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.domain/orders',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(order){
          this.content.addObject(App.Order.create(order))
        }, this)
      }
    });
    return this.content;
  }
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
   // The initial state for the router, contains every other.
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    goOrders: Ember.Route.transitionTo('orders'),
    goLocations: Ember.Route.transitionTo('locations'),
    goReports: Ember.Route.transitionTo('reports'),
    goUsers: Ember.Route.transitionTo('users'),
    goHelp: Ember.Route.transitionTo('help'),
    //Authenticated routes
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        redirectsTo: 'orders'
      }),
    orders: Ember.Route.extend({
      route:'/orders',
      initialState: 'index',
      //Orders view.
      index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
            name:'ordersList', 
            context: App.Order.findAll()
          });
        }
      })
    })
  })
});

App.initialize();
```

And in my template (simplified):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="orders">
    {{#each order in controller.content}}
<p>id: {{order.ord_id}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

With this I don't get and error but nothing shows up. If I paste he JSON in the context of the connectOutlet it works though. Is there a problem with my findAll() function?

Comment: You want to pass either `App.Order.find()` or `App.store.findAll(App.Order)` to the `connectOutlets` call instead of `App.Order.findAll()`

Comment: When I pass App.store.findAll(App.Order) I get an error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'App.store.findAll') Isn't that for Ember-data? I'm not using it.

Comment: If I do this {{#each order in controller}} i get this error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.addArrayObserver(this)')

Comment: As you are declaring `var content`, you should not use `this.content`, but just the `content` variable. Does it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this one:

```
findAll: function(){
      var content = [];
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.domain/orders',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(order){
          content.addObject(App.Order.create(order))
        }, this)
      }
    });
    return content;
  }
```

As you see, i just removed the this pointer two times. I think the this pointer in this case  points to an the Order class, which does not have a content property. But you want to reference the var you defined. Therefore it should be without this.

**Note: I do also have trouble from time to time with the this pointer, when fetching data. But this structure has always worked for me so far. So it should work, but my explanation might not be perfect.**

Comment: I think that content needs to be a property of Order because before the data is returned the template will use the empty array and then it's populated when the data is fetched. The data is fetched ok. Maybe I'm not binding it correctly with the template?

Comment: Did you try my approach? I guess not. What you basically say is, that you fetch your orders per JSON and you want to set those orders as content in your oder class. This is just wrong. Try my approach and you will likely be fine. Otherwise post a jsFiddle, so that we can discuss about running code.

Comment: Yes I tried it and it does not give an error but same result - can't access the data.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was with my AJAX call but I tried your solution with getJSON and it worked. Thanks for your help.