# Trying to use jsonp with ember-data, and unable to use Ember App's store.createRecord in custom adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use ember-data with jsonp by overridding DS.RESTAdapter's `findAll` [(based on the answer to this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383189/cant-load-external-json-in-ember-js).

```
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({});

App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.EventAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  findAll: function() {
    var events = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: '...',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response) {
        response.results.forEach(function(event) {
          events.addObject(App.ApplicationStore.createRecord('event', event));
        }, this);
      }
    });
    return events;
  }
});

App.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('event');
  }
});
```

I first tried using `events.addObject(App.Event.create(event))`, but ember returned an error: "You should not call create on a model. Instead, call store.createRecord with the attributes you would like to set".

The issue is, `App.ApplicationStore.createRecord` is undefined, so I'm stuck without a way to instantiate Events. Anyone know what's going on? If there's a completely different approach to getting jsonp to work with ember-data, that's fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kaungst's answer was really helpful, but ember was still throwing an error. It led me to a solution that works, though:

```
App.EventSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    return {'events': payload};
  }
});

App.EventAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  findAll: function(store) {
    var events = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: '...',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response) {
        response.results.forEach(function(event) {
          events.addObject(store.createRecord('event', event));
        }, this);
      }
    });
    return events;
  }
});
```

I overrode DS.RESTSerializer's `normalizePayload` instead of `extractFindAll`, which fixed the subsequent error I was getting. Additionally, I defined `App.EventSerializer` (singular) instead of `App.EventsSerializer`.

Answer (score 1):

This parsing of the response seems more like a job for the RESTSerializer than the RESTAdapter(though you will still need the adapter if you need to set the dataType/url)

Not 100% sure, but it looks like your reponse is an array that doesn't have the correct key
as stated in the [jsonapi.org documenation](http://www.jsonapi.org/format)?

If this is the case, you'd want to create a serializer for events like this

```
App.EventsSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractFindAll: function(store, type, rawPayload, id, requestType) {
        this._super(store, type, { 'events': rawPayload }, id, requestType);
    }
});
```

The above serializer will reformat the response to be ember-data readable(as per the above documentation), and ember-data will take care of the rest

[DS.RESTSerializer documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html)

As an aside, the current store is passed as the first parameter to DS.RESTAdapter.findAll, so you should access the store through that parameter

<\EDIT>
including [DS.RESTAdapter.findall source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.11/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L335)

Comment: Thanks a ton - this was really helpful! Getting the current store from the first argument to findAll did the trick, and the serializer change led me in the right direction - after your changes, I was getting  `Error while processing route: events Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined`. I found a different way of normalizing the payload which worked, so I'll post that as a separate answer.

Comment: Happy to help, glad you were able to figure it out!